# issue with unordered_map on mac

Tags: c++, qt

I want to compile a c++ source code that i found. The code works well on linux (Qt), but on Mac OS X (10.9.5) i have this error on QT :

```
/Users/Anass/test2/segmenter.h:19: erreur : 'unordered_map' file not    
found
#include <unordered_map>
         ^
```

and when i replace the

```
"#include <unordered_map>" by "#include<tr1/unordered_map>"
```

the line is underlined with green and the error change to this line where :

```
/Users/Anass/test2/segmenter.h:21: erreur : 'unordered_set' file not    
found
#include <unordered_set>
         ^
```

I kept the same .pro file (defined for linux) :

```
QT       += core gui opengl
greaterThan(QT_MAJOR_VERSION, 4): QT += widgets

TARGET = Superfacets
CONFIG   += console
CONFIG   -= app_bundle

TEMPLATE = app

QMAKE_CXXFLAGS_RELEASE += -fpermissive
QMAKE_CXXFLAGS_DEBUG += -fpermissive
QMAKE_CXXFLAGS += -std=c++0x
QMAKE_CXXFLAGS_RELEASE -= -O2
QMAKE_CXXFLAGS_RELEASE += -O3


SOURCES += main.cpp \
Vertex3D.cpp \
Vertex2D.cpp \
Triangle.cpp \
Timer.cpp \
segmenter.cpp \
Reader.cpp \
normals.cpp \
meshvisualizer.cpp \
Edge.cpp \
dialogs.cpp \
colormapper.cpp

HEADERS += \
Vertex3D.h \
Vertex2D.h \
Triangle.h \
Timer.h \
Sorting.h \
segmenter.h \
Reader.h \
normals.h \
meshvisualizer.h \
Mesh.h \
Edge.h \
dialogs.h \
colormapper.h


LIBS += -lGLU
```

The clang version is :

```
clang --version
Apple LLVM version 6.0 (clang-600.0.57) (based on LLVM 3.5svn)
Target: x86_64-apple-darwin13.4.0
Thread model: posix
```

I searched on google and i found that it could be related to "stdlib" but i'm really a specialist of compiling.

Any help please?

Comment: they were a commenst here, but they disappear how come ?

Comment: Try to compile with `-std=c++11` istead of `-std=c++0x`

Comment: i replace QMAKE_CXXFLAGS += -std=c++0x by QMAKE_CXXFLAGS += -std=c++11 , but the issue still exists

Comment: Check those answers: [What could cause clang to not find the unordered_map header?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26233011/what-could-cause-clang-to-not-find-the-unordered-map-header) and  [Why some include files only reside in tr1?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7870897/why-some-include-files-only-reside-in-tr1)

Comment: yes, i saw theses ones. However when i add the "-stdlib=libc++" i get this new issue :  erreur : invalid deployment target for -stdlib=libc++ (requires OS X 10.7 or later)"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A quick Google reveals [this fix](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24243176/how-to-specify-target-mac-os-x-version-using-qmake). Add

```
QMAKE_MACOSX_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET = 10.7
```

to your `.pro` file along with the aforementioned

```
QMAKE_CXXFLAGS += -std=c++11
```

Comment: sorry but i didn't find this fix. It works now. thanks !